# CCTV Camera Access Using Ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have developed the App using ionic framework and cordova. Is there any plugins / option to access CCTV camera using ionic framework and cordova ..?

Comment: You want to access camera option in mobile? or external CCTV camera

Comment: I want to access External CCTV Camera Live video into my Application. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible if you able to access your CCTV camera Images in your mobile

Comment: Yet I have not clear idea about CCTV Camera access. The [link](http://jonashartmann.github.io/webcam-directive/#/) is reference for accessing camera , till i has not find a solution for  CCTV camera access. Let me know any option for access CCTV Camera?

Comment: Many CCTV cameras transmit [MJPEG (Motion Jpeg)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) You might be able to match it with a [video plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=video)

Comment: Thank You @JesseMonroy650 . I will try it.

Comment: @SATHIYASARAVANABABU were you able to develop this application?

Comment: @SATHIYASARAVANABABU , Are you able to develop the app ? I have same requirement , please let me know that is it possible

Comment: can you share how did you execute this?

Comment: hey sathiya can you share your progress on this please?